# SQL query that returns payment amounts that occur more than once per customer but excludes amounts with a single occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, payment

If I have a [Customer] who makes a [Payment] on a given [Date]
Then how can I query multiple occurrences of the same payment value on customer-by-customer basis, without specifying the Customer?

I would want to return something like this:

| [Customer] | [Payment] | [Date] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1/1 |
| A | 5 | 1/4 |
| B | 4 | 1/2 |
| B | 4 | 1/3 |
| C | 9 | 1/1 |
| C | 9 | 1/5 |

so on and so forth..

Comment: I want to exclude amounts that don't have more than one occurrence for each borrower. 
e.g. Customer A made 5 payments  of 1,5,5,4,6; I would only want to return the payments of 5

Comment: What DBMS are using and does it have window functions?

Comment: SqlServer Mgmt Studio 18. Im not sure if it has window functions

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL Server, partition by is very useful.You can group the columns and give new values.

[MSSQL Server partition by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In this situation, Customer name and Payment date must be grouping so duplicate values are findable.

Customer table and payment table join code :

```
select c.Name,p.PaymentDate,p.PaymentValue from dbo.Customer c inner join dbo.Payment p on c.CustomerId = p.CustomerId order by 1,2
```

Customer table and Payment table example values:

[image: values]

Query for finding duplicate values:

```
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT c.Name,p.PaymentDate,p.PaymentValue,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Name,p.PaymentValue ORDER BY p.PaymentDate asc) AS [rn] from dbo.Customer c inner join dbo.Payment p on c.CustomerId = p.CustomerId ) select * from cte where rn>1
```

Query Result:

[image: Duplicate Values]

Comment: This will return customers that have two identical payments on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` if you want the original data:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.customer = t.customer and
                    t2.payment = t.payment and
                    t2.date <> t.date
             );
```

If you want only the customers, you can use `group by`.  This is actually one of the rare cases where you can use `group by` with `select distinct`:

```
select distinct customer
from t
group by customer, payment
having min(date) <> max(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query outputs all the payments with duplicate amounts by customer.

```
drop table if exists #temp;
go
create table #temp(
  Customer      nvarchar(50) not null,
  Payment       int not null,
  PayDate       date not null);

insert into #temp values
('A', 1, '20210101'),
('A', 5, '20210101'),
('A', 5, '20210101'),
('A', 4, '20210101'),
('A', 6, '20210101'),
('B', 4, '20210101'),
('B', 4, '20210101'),
('C', 9, '20210101'),
('C', 9, '20210101');

with pay_cte(Customer, Payment, pay_cnt) as (
    select Customer, Payment, count(*)
    from #temp
    group by Customer, Payment
    having count(*)>1)
select *
from #temp t
     join pay_cte p on t.Customer=p.Customer
                       and t.Payment=p.Payment;
```

```
Customer    Payment PayDate     Customer    Payment pay_cnt
A           5       2021-01-01  A           5       2
A           5       2021-01-01  A           5       2
B           4       2021-01-01  B           4       2
B           4       2021-01-01  B           4       2
C           9       2021-01-01  C           9       2
C           9       2021-01-01  C           9       2
```